# User-defined ordering - Extra column or table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Say I have a series of articles encoded in a database which are displayed on the front-end of a web site.

If support for custom-defined ordering is added, how could/should this be represented in the database ?

P.S: There might be a case where an article is displayed in more than one list.

Comment: Ordering options should be based on the structure of your tables, and would probably only add clutter as metadata, unless you foresee it changing often.  I personally would keep the definition of orders defined only in the application.

Comment: "I personally would keep the definition of orders defined only in the application." In an XML file for example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to store user-defined ordering in the database is as rows of data in tables. To do that, you need columns to

- identify the user,
- identify the article, and
- identify the order.

The first two are easy. There are several different ways to store the order.  The design goal is usually to reduce the need to rewrite the order.

```
create table user_defined_order (
  user_id integer not null references users (user_id),
  article_id integer not null references articles (article_id),
  sort_order <sort_data_type> not null,
  primary key (user_id, article_id),
  unique (user_id, sort_order)
);
```

The last constraint, `unique (user_id, sort_order)`, is application-dependent.

**sort_data_type options**

Different data types give you different options for inserting and for changing the order.  The most commonly used are

- integer without gaps (inserting requires rewriting a bunch of rows)
- integer with gaps (insert into a gap, rewrite a bunch of rows when a gap closes)
- float (insert halfway between existing floats, rewrite when splitting fails)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, then every user can display the orders in a different order. Assuming that every user has an id, then you would need a table consisting of three fields, user id/article id/display order, where user id and article id provide a composite primary key for the table.